# Does compactness and path-connectedness imply contractibleness?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a path-connected topological space and $A\subset X$ a compact and path-connected subspace. I would like to conclude that $A$ is contractible and so I'm wondering if these two hypothesis are enough or if I have to do some more assumption on $A$ in order to get the claim. I cannot solve this doubt, so I would like to ask you if you know something about it.

Thank you very much!

P.S.: if it can be useful, my $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: After considering many pathological examples, I recalled the existence of the circle.

Comment: Mmm you are right...so I have no choice, I must prove that my A is contractible without theorems or criterions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Since no one has posted an answer so far, you could also change your question to ask about the specific $A$ you are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you, but it is ok. We can consider this post closed. Thank you very much!